# PDO two similar queries - only the first inserts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form where the user can insert up to five line items for an invoice. The easiest way for me to do this is to just do five inserts and do a `isset` check before each query. However, the problem is if I try to run the two queries one after another only the first one inserts the data. I know I can combine them into one PDO query (and that does in fact work), but it does not suit my needs. **The second query does not insert.**

```
// Connect to the database
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_DATABASE",$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);

//Set all the data here 
$receiptid = $_POST['receiptid'];
    // .. the rest of the POST data gets set here.


//Insert first line item
$sql = "INSERT INTO lineitems (receiptid, service, description, quantity, unitprice, linetotal) 
        VALUES (:receiptid, :service, :description, :quantity, :unitprice, :linetotal)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':receiptid'=>$receiptid,
                    ':service'=>$service,
                    ':description'=>$description,
                    ':quantity'=>$quantity,
                    ':unitprice'=>$unitprice,
                    ':linetotal'=>$linetotal));

//Insert second line item
$sql = "INSERT INTO lineitems (receiptid, service2, description2, quantity2, unitprice2, linetotal2) 
        VALUES (:receiptid, :service2, :description2, :quantity2, :unitprice2, :linetotal2)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':receiptid'=>$receiptid,
                    ':service2'=>$service2,
                    ':description2'=>$description2,
                    ':quantity2'=>$quantity2,
                    ':unitprice2'=>$unitprice2,
                    ':linetotal2'=>$linetotal2));
```

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but if it's going into the same table, shouldn't it have the same fieldnames in the query? Or do you have one called `service`, `service2`, etc?

Comment: @andrewsi not a silly question at all. Probably the question I should have asked myself 2 hour ago. This would be the problem.

Comment: Ah, glad to have helped - sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your table really have different columns for each entered lineitem number (i.e. service2, descriptions2, etc.)?

Perhaps you need to change the field names in your second insert to match those in the first.

If you were handling cases where you did not get expected query result properly (i.e. checking your execution results and looking at the errors if something fails, You would be able to get to the source of the problem in a hurry.)

Comment: Yes! this is the problem. I looked into everything and couldn't figure out what it was.. but the problems was so obvious!

Comment: Again,  It is good to make a habit of putting in conditional logic to handle unexpected query failures and output the MySQL error in some fashion.  It will make stupid typos and things like that readily apparent.